# Find go version

Tags: go

Why can't I find the version of go on my ubuntu 14.04? The output of `go version` doesn't give me info on whether the `go` is 1.7 or 1.8. Any ideas?

```
$ go version
go version xgcc (Ubuntu 4.9.3-0ubuntu4) 4.9.3 linux/amd64
$ uname -a
Linux jin1-hp1 3.19.0-65-generic #73~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jun 29 21:05:22 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Following another post, I found it from the command of `docker`, but I would like to find the version from `go` command itself.

```
$ docker version
Client:
 Version:      1.11.2
 API version:  1.23
 Go version:   go1.5.4
 Git commit:   b9f10c9
 Built:        Wed Jun  1 21:47:50 2016
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host?
```

Comment: Thanks @OliviaRuth, it works.  Please write a answer on this so I can accept it.

Answer (score 12):

Perhaps write a small program to print [runtime.Version()](https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#Version) ?

Comment: I got the same resultl when printing `runtime.Version()`:  `$ go run te.go
xgcc (Ubuntu 4.9.3-0ubuntu4) 4.9.3`

Comment: There is no need to write the small program to get the version of `go` what you can do is that go to the terminal in ubuntu and run command `go version`  and you would receive the version of your go.
`go version go1.10.4 linux/amd64` 

Also, for new comers, if you are writing the small program don't forget to add import of `runtime` package. Cheers